# How to specify the character set used by the page in the HTTP header for WOFF2?

Tags: apache, performance, fonts, drupal-8, webfonts

I hosted the google font on my Drupal 8 site.

When I scan my site with different tool, I have this error message :

> Specify a character set in your response HTTP headers No character
>   sets are specified in the HTTP headers of the following resources.
>   Specifying a character set speeds up the display of pages in the
>   browser.
>
> https://www.domaine.com/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/fonts/source-sans-pro-v11-latin-700.woff2
>   https://www.domaine.com/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/fonts/source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.woff2
>   https://www.domaine.com/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/fonts/source-sans-pro-v11-latin-regular.woff2
>
> Specifying the character set used by the page in the HTTP Content-Type
>   header allows the browser to start its analysis right away.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOFF has its own [binary file format](https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/), so there is really no need to specify a character set.

> Specifying a character set speeds up the display of pages in the
>   browser.
>
> Specifying the character set used by the page in the HTTP Content-Type
>   header allows the browser to start its analysis right away.

This is used for html pages: most pages use something like `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the html code. The problem is that the browser doesn't know the character set until it reaches and parses that `<meta>` tag. If that character set is different from the default setting, the browser has to reparse the page.

If the character set is specified in the HTTP headers instead:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

the browser knows the character set before it starts parsing the page.